# Variables within functions within DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics

Hi I am just beginning to learn Mathematica and this is my first time I have been exposed to any type of coding. I am encountering a problem in a basic physics problem. For example we are always interested in solving the motion of a projectile with differential equation

`x''[t]+k x'[t]==0`

Usually though the initial conditions of the velocity in the x (and y direction) depend on the angle (theta) and the magnitude of the initial velocity (v0). Therefore the initial conditions usually look like:

`x[0]==0,x'[0]==v0 Cos[theta]`

My question is there a way to work around `DSolve` so that it can output a solution of the form x[t,v0,theta]? I have tried calling the initial condition `v0x` and simply defining that as

`v0x:=v0 Cos[theta]`

But I haven't any luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sol = First @ DSolve[{D[x[t, v0, theta], {t, 2}] + k D[x[t, v0, theta], t] == 0, 
  x[0, v0, theta] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][0, v0, theta] == v0 Cos[theta]}, x, {t, v0, 
  theta}]
(*  {x -> Function[{t, v0, theta}, (E^(-k t) (-1 + E^(k t)) v0 Cos[theta])/k]}  *)
```

Usage:

```
x[t, 10, Pi/4] /. sol
(*  (5 Sqrt[2] E^(-k t) (-1 + E^(k t)))/k  *)
```

(Note this is not projectile motion under gravity, but it gives you the idea how to use `DSolve`, I hope.)

Comment: This was what I was going for. Genius. I am going to play around with Mathematica and see if I can solve in y motion and how to use the solutions to plot. Thank you!

Comment: @phandaman You're welcome.  Good luck!